# PL/SQL: ORA-01747 error: invalid specification user.table.column, table.column or column

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, ora-01747

I am trying to learn PL/SQL and I have a problem creating procedure.

I want to create a procedure that will automatically increase the commission by 10% after the end of
trial period - 3 months. I need to create a scheduler,
who will activate the procedure every day and check whether the
condition is fulfilled.

My code:

```
create or replace procedure upd_sal(v_emp_id in employees.employee_id%type,
                                    v_h_date in employees.hire_date%type) is
  cursor c_emp_sal_update(cv_emp_id employees.employee_id%type) is
  select commission_pct
    from employees
   where employee_id = cv_emp_id
     for update of commission_pct nowait;
begin
  for v_c in c_emp_sal_update(v_emp_id) loop
    if v_c.add_months(sysdate, -3) = v_h_date then
      update employees
         set commission_pct = commission_pct + 0, 10
       where current of c_emp_sal_update;
    end if;
  end loop;
end upd_sal;
/
```

Can you advise me please?

Thank you

Comment: SQL Server != Oracle - please correct your tags.

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: @stickybit: Of course you are right asking for table definitions. However, didn't you recognize the `employees` table from the standard Oracle example?

Answer (score 0):

Wellcome to the world of PL/SQL and Oracle's misleading error messages ;-)

I think it's just one typo and one syntax error. Adding 10% should be something like

```
set commission_pct = commission_pct * 1.10
```

and secondly, the `addmonth` muss not have a variable in front of it:

```
if add_months(sysdate, -3) = v_h_date then
```

BTW, personally, I'd update all employees in one statement instead of a loop, but that wasn't your question :-)

```
create or replace procedure upd_sal is
begin
  update employees
     set commission_pct = commission_pct * 1.1
   where add_months(trunc(sysdate), -3) = trunc(hire_date);
end upd_sal;
/
```

Comment: The error message seems fair - `10` isn't a valid column specification. The update is expecting something like `set commission_pct = commission_pct + 123, col2 = 456, col3 = 'bananas' where...` but instead of a column name, it sees `10`. What other error message could it give?

Comment: Well, I disagree. I usually understand Oracle error messages only after I learned the correct syntax and spot the error myself. I'm not complaning too much, though, as it keeps me in my job...

Comment: What error message would you suggest in this situation? If you write `update emp set name = 'JONES', 42;` what should it say?

Comment: Error trying to update one column with two values?

Comment: How could it possibly assume there was an attempt to use two values to update `ename` in my example? Surely the best it could do would be something like `"42" is not a column in table "SCOTT"."EMP"`. It's a syntax checker, not a mind reader.